# Upvote reputation not added

Tags: bug, reputation, voting

I recently posted an answer which had `2 upvotes` and was `accepted` -> Which should result in `+35 reputation`. The below pictures show that I indeed should have 35 points. 
[CSS style heading - background must cover only text with a bottom border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30794685/css-style-heading-background-must-cover-only-text-with-a-bottom-border/30794739#30794739)

[image][image]
But I only got 25 reputation, and my reputation post shows this:
 [image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got your 35 rep, just not all on the same day.

[image]

From your rep history (by time and not by post), you had an upvote and accept around yesterday.  On the twelfth, you had an upvote.  The total does come up to 35, but it didn't all happen on the same day.

Comment: I see. Woops, I wasn't looking carefully.